# OpenGL height based fog

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I am reading  [Inigo Quilez Fog](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/fog/fog.htm) article and I just can't understand few things when he talks about fog based on height.

He has a shader function about height based fog but I have problems understanding how to make it work.

He uses this function to apply fog

```
vec3 applyFog( in vec3  rgb,       // original color of the pixel
               in float distance ) // camera to point distance
{
    float fogAmount = 1.0 - exp( -distance*b );
    vec3  fogColor  = vec3(0.5,0.6,0.7);
    return mix( rgb, fogColor, fogAmount );
}
```

then he has the other one based to calculage fog based on height

```
    vec3 applyFog( in vec3  rgb,      // original color of the pixel
               in float distance, // camera to point distance
               in vec3  rayOri,   // camera position
               in vec3  rayDir )  // camera to point vector
{
    float fogAmount = c * exp(-rayOri.y*b) * (1.0-exp( -distance*rayDir.y*b ))/rayDir.y;
    vec3  fogColor  = vec3(0.5,0.6,0.7);
    return mix( rgb, fogColor, fogAmount );
}
```

I can understand how the shader works but I don't know how to use it with mine. For now I am just trying to learn how the whole fog world in GLSL works but it looks that there is just a lot about it to learn. :D

```
    #version 400 core

in vec3 Position;
in vec3 Normal;
//in vec4 positionToCamera;
//in float visibility;

uniform vec3 color;
uniform vec3 CameraPosition;
uniform float near;
uniform float far;

uniform vec3 fogColor;
uniform bool enableBlending;

uniform float c;
uniform float b;

uniform int fogType;

vec3 applyFogDepth( vec3  rgb,  // original color of the pixel
     float distance,            // camera to point distance
     vec3  rayOri,              // camera position
     vec3  rayDir)              // camera to point vector
{
    //float cc = 1.0;
    //float bb = 1.1;
    float fogAmount = c * exp(-rayOri.y*b) * (1.0 - exp(-distance*rayDir.y*b)) / rayDir.y;
    return mix(rgb,  fogColor,  fogAmount );
}

// Fog with Sun factor
vec3 applyFogSun( vec3  rgb,// original color of the pixel
     float distance,        // camera to point distance
     vec3  rayDir,          // camera to point vector
     vec3  sunDir)          // sun light direction
{
    float fogAmount = 1.0 - exp(-distance*b);
    float sunAmount = max(dot(rayDir, sunDir), 0.0);

    vec3 fog = mix(fogColor, // bluish
        vec3(1.0, 0.9, 0.7), // yellowish
        pow(sunAmount, 8.0));

    return mix(rgb, fog, fogAmount);
}

//Exponential fog
vec3 applyFog( vec3  rgb, // original color of the pixel
         float distance)  // camera to point distance
{
    float fogAmount = 1.0 - exp(-distance*b);
    return mix(rgb, fogColor, fogAmount);
    //return rgb*( exp(-distance*b)) + fogColor*(1.0 - exp(-distance*b));
}

float LinearizeDepth(float depth)
{
    float z = depth * 2.0 - 1.0; // Back to NDC 
    return (2.0 * near * far) / (far + near - z * (far - near));
}

out vec4 gl_FragColor;
void main(void) {

    vec3 fog = vec3(0.0);
    //-5.0f, 900.0f, 400.0f camera coord
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 1200.0, -6000.0);
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPosition - Position);
    vec3 direction = normalize(CameraPosition - Position);

    float depth = LinearizeDepth(gl_FragCoord.z) / far;
    switch (fogType) {
        case 0:
            fog = applyFog(color, depth);
            break;
        case 1:
            fog = applyFogSun(color, depth, direction, lightDirection);
            break;
        case 2:
            //fog = mix(applyFog(color, depth), applyFogDepth(color, depth, CameraPosition, CameraPosition - Position), 0.5)   ;
            fog = applyFogDepth(color, depth, CameraPosition, CameraPosition - Position);
            break;
    }

    //calculate light
    float diff = max(dot(Normal, lightDirection), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * color;

    float fogAmount = 1.0 - exp(-depth*b);

    vec3 finalColor = vec3(0.0);
    if (enableBlending)
        finalColor = mix(diffuse, fog, fogAmount);
    else
        finalColor = fog;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor,1.0);
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(LinearizeDepth(visibility) / far), 1.0f);
}
```

The first image is the first function to apply fog and in the second image is the second function.

[image: apply fog]
[image]

Comment: the function says the argument is `// camera to point vector`. `CameraPosition - Position` is the position to camera vector. Try `Position - CameraPosition`.

Comment: No that does not work, I have tried that and I have tried normalized values. I am stuck here for 2 days now and I thought it would be nice to ask and move one trying other things with fog. I will try `-(Position - CameraPosition)` just to see the result even thought its the same vector as `CameraPosition - Position`

Comment: How's the result supposed to look like?

Comment: You should have more fog at lower ground. If you go to the link at the end of the article there is a great picture that shows the difference. I would like to tell you but my shader is now to working and I am using a low poly mesh now.

Comment: If there is another way to create shader that has more fog at lower parts in mainlans like UE Exponential Height Fog i would be happy to read about it. 

So far it has been 3 days that I am trying to fix and figure out how does non constant fog works, and I just cant see a solution so far.